# How to List Helm Chart Versions By Date?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm looking at the helm chart versions from the jupyterhub helm repo: `https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/index.yaml`

When I use `helm search  -l jupyterhub/jupyterhub`, the versions come out in the order that they appear in the `index.yaml`, which is not the order in which they are created (according to the `created` field in `index.yaml`)

Is there a way to get the version list sorted by date created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the helm point of view no. But you can tweak the output to get what you want, although it's pretty tricky since the versioning/tagging hasn't been consistent for `jupyterhub/jupyterhub` for example.

Anyhow, I came up with this bash/Ruby one-liner but it's picking it up directly from: `https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/index.yaml`

```
$ curl -s https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/index.yaml | ruby -ryaml -rjson -rdate -e 'puts YAML.load(ARGF)["entries"]["binderhub"].sort_by {|hsh| hsh["created"] }'
```